# MATLAB - How to force a specific variable to be stored in memory?

Tags: matlab, memory, cell-array

I have a cell array of classifiers (for example, decision trees)
trainmodel = cell(1,100000). And sometimes this thing gets really big, so is there any way to tell MATLAB that if this variable is too big, just store it in the memory? Of course I can use matfile, but the thing is that if it's not too big then it would be slower. Please help me, thank you very much. 
UPDATE: The number of trees is known beforehand, and we can assume that the trees are identical in memory size. So what I'd like to do is to measure how much memory is consumed by an individual tree.

Comment: Do you mean stored on disc? MATLAB's variables are already stored in memory.

Comment: @excaza: I mean storing in matfile and things like that. My computer has 16GB rams, windows 10, matlab R2016b but it still gets out of memory error :(

Comment: Check the configuration of the [Virtual Memory](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2840886/if-windows-virtual-memory-is-too-low-you-can-increase-it-but-there-are-trade-offs.html)

Answer (score 0):

[datastore](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/what-is-a-datastore.html) function is specially designed for tall arrays and for [machine learning](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/statistics-and-machine-learning-with-big-data-using-tall-arrays.html)

Comment: But how do you adapt it to store a decision tree? :(